# preg Regex: Need to capture both a keyword and an ID that follows it enclosed in braces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Suppose there is a string of text

```
blah blah blah CONTENT{asdfkuydiusyhv} blah blah blah VALUE{jdiuvhgy54bkd8} blah blah blah
```

I need a php regex (preg_match_all) that will capture all the keywords and values into an array, where

```
$array = 0=> $keywords[0] = CONTENT
             $keywords[1] = VALUE
         1=> $results[0] = asdfkuydiusyhv
             $results[1] = jdiuvhgy54bkd8
```

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried something ? Show your code/attempts

Comment: does this help? (\w+){(\w+)}

Comment: Here's the original that doesn't work - done by someone else - that I am trying to debug:
    preg_match_all('/(?<![\/\w@\.:])' . preg_quote(strtoupper($keyword), '/') . '([a-zA-Z0-9\.\?\/&:=_-]*?)(?![\/\?\w&@:=_-])(?!\.\w)/' . $regexpmodifier, $text, $keywordresults);

as you can see, I need to search for specific keywords one at a time; it will be running in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the keywords are always uppercase, if not adjust with `i` or add `a-z`:

```
preg_match_all('/ ([A-Z]+){([^}]+)}/', $string, $matches);
$keywords = $matches[1];
$results  = $matches[2];
```

To look for specific keywords something like:

```
$keywords = array('CONTENT'); //etc..

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    preg_match("/ $keyword{([^}]+)}/", $string, $match);
    $results[] = $match[1];
}
```

Comment: This gets close, but I will be executing code that specifically looks for the keywords one at a time, so the regex needs to search for the specific keyword rather than any word that precedes a left brace.  I am attempting to debug existing code, which I will place in the comments above since they asked for it.

Comment: Added some code to loop thru keywords and match those.

Comment: Closer, thanks.  The right values are captured, but not into a multidimensional array as in the example results.  I think this may be because there could be more than one instance of each keyword in a string of text, and all of them need to be captured, each with it's own element in the keyword array and results array.

Comment: The php I can handle.  How do you make it capture every instance of CONTENT and put the results into an array.  The original code did that except the result values were empty.

Comment: Got it!  Your for loop version didn't use preg_match_all; when I used that it works great.  Thanks.